# Can't see the validation message error of model in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

As I can show the error validation messages of model, in the view template?

My model (screenshot)

[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmc4X.jpg)

Thank!

Comment: What is not working for you ? You should be posting your model, controller and view codes.

Comment: It is much, much code and i can not show

who I have to do to put the error in the view?

Comment: Do you have code for show error in view?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your validation with:

```
validates :exp_name,  presence: {message: "your custom message"}
validates_length_of :exp_name, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 100, message: "your custom message"
```

Put these lines in the view to show the error:

```
<% if @experience.errors.any? %>
  <div>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@experience.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this logo from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @experience.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```